# Python requests PUT

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication

I need to send a PUT request with authentication in one time.
When I use Postman for that and input

```
 headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic Token', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
 Authorization = Basic Auth Username = 'login' Password = 'pass'
 Body = data
```

everything goes well.
If I try to write request in python:

```
req = r.put(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Basic Token', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('login','password'), data=data)
```

I get response 400 Bad Request

Whats wrong with my request?

Comment: You can't use both `Authorization: Basic Token` **and** Basic Auth authentication. Pick one or the other, as basic auth requires the `Authorization` header to be set using a specific format.

Comment: Using both in Postman and in the requests module is liable to result in different unexpected interactions. Without looking at the code I can't tell you right now what will happen in either case, but you could end up with `Authorization: Basic Token` (with username and password ignored), `Authorization: Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=` (the `HTTPBasicAuth` auth argument overwriting the header), with headers combined into one, or two separate headers, depending on how Postman handles this (requests will use one or the other).

Comment: So now  I'm trying to send this request,  without auth, and it's still 400
req = r.put(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Basic Token', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=data)

Comment: We can't debug that, you didn't share anything about what the server expects. A 400 error can mean any number of issues, including the format of `data` not being correct. If you are sending JSON, don't manually encode the value for `data`, but use `json=` instead (and not set a `Content-Type` header).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for your case, but I did use Basic authentication a while ago to authenticate with the Reddit API.

Here's my code:

```
import requests

client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("put something here","put something here")

headers = {"User-Agent": "manage your reddit easily by u/0xff"}

code = "ajkldjfalkdjflajfd;lakdjfa"

data = {
    "code":code,
    "grant_type":"authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/authorize_callback"
}

r = requests.post("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", auth=client_auth, data=data, headers=headers);

print(r.content)
```

Just make the appropriate changes for your case and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting authorization information *twice*, and different HTTP libraries will handle this conflict in different ways.

[HTTP Basic Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) uses the `Authorization` header, encoding the username and password (separated by `:`) as base64 and setting the header to the value `Basic` plus space plus the base64 encoded string. You are telling both POSTman and `requests` to set the `Authorization` header to the string `Basic Token` *and* to use a username and password for Basic Auth, so the clients will have to make a choice between these two options.

Trying this out in requests version 2.25.1 I see that the `auth` information will win here:

```
>>> from requests import Session, Request
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> req = Request(
...     "PUT",
...     "http://example.com",
...     headers={
...         'Authorization': 'Basic Token',
...         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
...     },
...     auth=HTTPBasicAuth('login','password'),
...     data=b"{}"
... )
>>> session = Session()
>>> prepped = session.prepare_request(req)
>>> from pprint import pp
>>> pp(dict(prepped.headers))
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'Accept': '*/*',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Authorization': 'Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Content-Length': '2'}
```

The above session creates a [prepared request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) so I can inspect the effect of the `auth` argument on the headers given to the request, and as you can see the `Authorization` header has been set to a base64 value created from the `login` and `password` pair.

It looks like Postman will do the same, the UI even tells you so:

[image: partial screenshot of the Postman desktop client UI showing a tooltip over the Authorization header warning that it is duplicate and will be replaced by a generated value]

You didn't share any details about what web service you are using or what expectations that service has for headers or request contents. If this a OAuth2-protected service, then you should not confuse obtaining a token with using that token for subsequent requests to protected URLs. For a `grant_type="password"` token request, it *could* be that the server expects you to use the username and password in a Basic Auth header, but it may also expect you to use `client_id` and `client_secret` values for that purpose and put the username and password in the POST body. You'll need to carefully read the documentation.

Other than that, you could replace your destination URL with an online HTTP echo service such as httpbin. The URL `https://httpbin.org/put` will give you a JSON response with the headers that the service received as well as the body of your request.

Further things you probably should be aware of:

- requests can encode JSON data for you if you use the `json` argument, and if you do, the `Content-Type` header is *generated for you*.
- You don't need to import the `HTTPBasicAuth` object, as `auth=(username, password)` (as a tuple) works too.